# Insert simple JSON object into SQLite TEXT column using C API

Tags: c, json, sqlite

I want to store a JSON object in a TEXT column using SQLite C API. My JSON object contains only numbers, strings, and booleans, no nested objects or arrays. My goal is to emulate variable number of columns.

Consider a table:
`CREATE TABLE t (i INTEGER, j TEXT);`

I'm currently using a prepared statement like this:

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO t (j) VALUES (:1);";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
const char *buf = build_my_json_object(); // E.g. {"foo":101,"bar":102,"baz":103}
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, buf);
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. Specifically, is there a way to insert a JSON object without having to build the JSON first.

To query the JSON object in the TEXT column, I've found it quite handy to use `json_each()`, because then I don't need a JSON parser. I'm missing an equally convenient way to insert a JSON object, without a JSON serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, as I finally found a satisfactory solution.

I decided to use a temporary table:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TEMP TABLE kv (k, v);", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I populate the temporary table with my JSON key/value pairs:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO kv VALUES (:1, :2);", -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, key, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, value); // Bind by value type.
sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

This temporary table is then used to populate the `j` column of table `t`:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO t (i, j) VALUES (:1, (SELECT json_group_object(k, v) FROM kv));", -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, 42); // Set value for column i.
sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

Here's a complete sequence of SQL statements that illustrates the approach:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INTEGER, j TEXT);
CREATE TEMP TABLE kv (k, v);
INSERT INTO kv VALUES ('k1', 7);
INSERT INTO kv VALUES ('k2', 'hello');
INSERT INTO kv VALUES ('k3', 1.23);
INSERT INTO t (i, j) VALUES (42, (SELECT json_group_object(k, v) FROM kv));
SELECT * FROM t;
```

The output from the last select statement is `42|{"k1":7,"k2":"hello","k3":1.23}`.